# AngularFire adding to array clears $scope variables

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm getting a weird problem when I add something to a nested AngularFire $asArray() object. Not sure how to explain it without pasting all my code so bear with me.

My template is as so:

```
<ion-content ng-controller='WorkoutCtrl as workoutCtrl' data-ng-init="init()">
  <div ng-hide="workoutCtrl.isExercising" class="card">
    <label class="item item-input">
      <input ng-enter="createExercise(newExercise)" ng-model="newExercise" type="text" placeholder="Type exercise here...">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div ng-click="startExercise()" class="card" ng-controller="ExerciseCtrl" ng-repeat="exercise in exercises" data-ng-init="init()">
    <div class="item item-divider">
      {{ exercise.name }}
    </div>
    <div class="item item-text-wrap">
      <button class="button" ng-click="createSet()" ng-show="exercise.isActive">
        Tap to add set
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-divider" ng-show="exercise.isActive">
      <button class="button icon ion-minus-circled" ng-click="addReps(-1)"></button>
      {{ exercise.numReps + ' reps' }}
      <button class="button icon ion-plus-circled" ng-click="addReps(1)"></button>
      <div class="range">
        <input type="range" name="volume" min="1" max="10" ng-model="exercise.numReps">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card bottom-btn-wrapper">
    <button ng-hide="workoutCtrl.isExercising" class="button button-block button-positive done-workout">
      I'm done working out!
    </button>
    <button ng-show="workoutCtrl.isExercising" ng-click="finishExercises()" class="button button-block button-positive done-exercise">
      Finish Exercise
    </button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

And here are my controllers:

```
controllers.controller('WorkoutCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  'FirebaseUrl',
  '$firebase',
  function ($scope, FirebaseUrl, $firebase) {
    var self = this;
    var fireRef;

    $scope.init = function () {
      self.isExercising = false;
      self.workoutId = 1;
      fireRef = new Firebase(FirebaseUrl + '/workouts/' + self.workoutId);

      $firebase(fireRef).$update({ date: new Date() });
      $scope.exercises = $firebase(fireRef.child('exercises')).$asArray();
    };

    $scope.createExercise = function (name) {
      $scope.newExercise = '';
      $scope.exercises.$add({ name: name });
    };

    $scope.finishExercises = function () {
      angular.forEach($scope.exercises, function (exercise) {
        exercise.isActive = false;
      });
      self.isExercising = false;
    };
  }
]);

controllers.controller('ExerciseCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  'FirebaseUrl',
  '$firebase',
  function ($scope, FirebaseUrl, $firebase) {
    var fireRef;

    $scope.init = function () {
      fireRef = new Firebase(FirebaseUrl + '/workouts/' + $scope.workoutCtrl.workoutId + '/exercises/' + $scope.exercise.$id + '/sets');

      $scope.exercise.isActive = false;
      $scope.exercise.numReps = '8';
      $scope.exercise.sets = $firebase(fireRef).$asArray();
    };

    $scope.startExercise = function () {
      $scope.finishExercises();
      $scope.exercise.isActive = true;
      $scope.workoutCtrl.isExercising = true;
    };

    $scope.addReps = function (repsToAdd) {
      var reps = parseInt($scope.exercise.numReps) + repsToAdd;

      if (reps > 0 && reps < 100) {
        $scope.exercise.numReps = reps.toString();
      }
    };

    $scope.createSet = function () {
      $scope.exercise.sets.$add({reps: $scope.exercise.numReps});
    };
  }
]);
```

The problem I am having is when I click the button that calls the createSet() method. This successfully creates a new object in my Firebase database, however after doing so, for some reason `$scope.exercise.isActive` and `$scope.numReps` no longer have value. Any clue what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is updates coming from the server without your `isActive` and `numReps` display properties.

1. WorkoutCtrl gets an initial set of exercise objects as a Firebase Array watching the entire exercises data tree.
2. ExerciseCtrl is initialized for one exercise object, adding local properties not in Firebase on the exercise record (`isActive`, `numReps`).
3. ExerciseCtrl.createSet() updates the excercise record through exercise.sets.$add().  You appear to count on the server providing updates only for the sets list.
4. However, the server also pushes an update to the WorkoutCtrl.excercises array, since one of the excercises changed.
5. The update to excercise wipes out the attributes you had added locally in the ExerciseCtrl scope.

You could verify this by using [$watch](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-watchcb-context) on the excercises array and observing when the updates come back.

I solved a similar problem by [extending the Firebase Array Factory](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-extending-the-factories-firebasearrayextendfactory) to return my custom wrapper object over the raw data records.  It's a bit of work to hook this up, but it provides a lot of freedom to add UI behavior modeling not stored in Firebase.  The WidgetFactory example is fairly close to what you would need.